# SQL log directory has too much dump file

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014, dump

My SQL Server 2014 is automatically creating SQL dump file. It is generating automatically to take all the spaces and hangs over the database.

> Error: 8310, Severity: 16, State: 1.
>   Cannot create (or open) named file mapping object 'Global\SQL_110_MEMOBJ_24_SQL14_0'. SQL Server performance counters are disabled.
>   Error: 3409, Severity: 16, State: 1.
>   Performance counter shared memory setup failed with error -1. Reinstall sqlctr.ini for this instance, and ensure that the instance login account has correct registry permissions.
>   Default collation: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS (us_english 1033)

[image: Error Log]
[image: Location]

Comment: First, make sure you're on the latest support version. If that doesn't stop the dumps, open a case with Microsoft. Dumps shouldn't happen - at all let alone at this frequency. **Disclaimer** I work for Microsoft.

Comment: Your errorlog does not match the quoted issue. Or is that just the top part of the errorlog and your quoted statement is further down?

Comment: That is additional information regarding issue.

Comment: I notice the database is installed to the C: drive. Is this a test or development environment? What version of SQL Server are you running exactly?

Comment: Management studio Version 12.0.2000.8

Comment: can you bring it up to SP2? 12.0.2000.8 is the RTM version and IIRC there has been at least 1 fix related to dumps though memory fails me on what it was about. Also, details from the .log and .txt file for the dump will be helpful. Just remember to review and make sure there's nothing in there you don't want the world to see before posting. Depending on the cause of the dump, you could have object names, SQL, etc...

Comment: It could be my database error upgrading from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2014.System stop to generating additional dump file when I detach the database from the server I need to check my database first. My apologies for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Reference [sql server 2008 automatically generate stack dump](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b5c6a5ec-d84a-4d45-a3d8-c39b62b939dc/sql-server-2008-automatically-generate-stack-dump?forum=sqldatabaseengine)

Set 'msdb' to single user mode and run the following command

> DBCC CHECKDB('msdb', REPAIR_REBUILD)

Reset 'msdb' to multiuser mode the same process for your error database.
This resolved our problem.